# Angular js value set using drop down change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to set text-box value using drop-down on change. please check my code

### HTML

```html
<select ng-model="select.id" ng-options="x.id as x.name for x in cars"
        ng-change="setPrice();">
</select>

<input type="text" ng-model=select.price/>
```

when i save this, i must send id. when user select value using drop down, second text-box model value should be set accordingly
as a example,

when user select `ford`, text-box model value should be `1000`

when user select `Fiat`, text-box model value should be `5000`

my java script code

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.cars = [
        {id:"1", name : "Ford", value : 1000},
        {id:"2",name : "Fiat", value : 5000},
        {id:"3",name : "Volvo", value : 6000}
    ];  

    $scope.setPrice = function (){
        $scope.select.price = $scope.select.value;
    }

});
```

can you help me to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to consider providing solution for your code without any modification in `ng-model` for both `select` and `input` as well..

There are two things you could do,

**1)** Pass the `select.id` to the `setPrice()` function like,

```
<select ng-model="select.id" ng-options="x.id as x.name for x in cars" ng-change="setPrice(select.id)">
```

**2)** Filter the actual `$scope.cars` array with the id passed in like,

```
$scope.setPrice = function(selectedId) {
   const data = $scope.cars.filter((item,i) => item.id === selectedId);
   $scope.select.price = data[0].value;
}
```

Filter function will give the result as a single value inside array and hence you can use `data[0].value`, to get the value.

After the two changes, your complete code would look like,

```js
let app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.selected = {}
$scope.cars = [
        {id:"1", name : "Ford", value : 1000},
        {id:"2",name : "Fiat", value : 5000},
        {id:"3",name : "Volvo", value : 6000}
    ]; 

    $scope.setPrice = function (selectedId){
      const data = $scope.cars.filter((item,i) => item.id === selectedId);
      $scope.select.price = data[0].value;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <select ng-model="select.id" ng-options="x.id as x.name for x in cars" ng-change="setPrice(select.id)">
  <input type="text" ng-model="select.price"/> 
</div>
```

> [**Working Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/yVZeDumu3EgSjy01)